# Pandas DataFrame compare columns to a threshold column using where()

Tags: python, pandas

I need to null values in several columns where they are less in absolute value than correspond values in the threshold column

```
        import pandas as pd
        import numpy as np
        df=pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Nevada', 'Nevada'],
          'key2': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002], 
          'data1': np.random.randn(5),
          'data2': np.random.randn(5),
           'threshold': [0.5,0.4,0.6,0.1,0.2]}).set_index(['key1','key2'])

                   data1    data2   threshold
key1    key2            
Ohio    2000    0.201240    0.083833    0.5
        2001    -1.993489   -1.081208   0.4
        2002    0.759038    -1.688769   0.6
Nevada  2001    -0.543916   1.412679    0.1
        2002    -1.545781   0.181224    0.2
```

this gives me an error "cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names"
    df.where(df.abs()>df['threshold'])

this works but obviously against a scalar
     df.where(df.abs()>0.5)

```
                       data1           data2    threshold
        key1    key2            
        Ohio    2000    NaN              NaN    NaN
                2001    -1.993489   -1.081208   NaN
                2002    0.759038    -1.688769   NaN
      Nevada    2001    -0.543916   1.412679    NaN
                2002    -1.545781        NaN    NaN
```

BTW, this does appear to be giving me an OK result - still want to find out how to do it with where() method

```
      df.apply(lambda x:x.where(x.abs()>x['threshold']),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly different option using the `DataFrame.gt` (greater than) method.

```
df[df.abs().gt(df['threshold'], axis='rows')]
Out[16]: 
# Output might not look the same because of different random numbers,
# use np.random.seed() for reproducible random number gen
Out[13]: 
                data1     data2  threshold
key1   key2                               
Ohio   2000       NaN       NaN        NaN
       2001  1.954543  1.372174        NaN
       2002       NaN       NaN        NaN
Nevada 2001  0.275814  0.854617        NaN
       2002       NaN  0.204993        NaN
```